# How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

My model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to save both `user1` and `user2` in that model:

```
user1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user2 = User.objects.get(pk=2)
sample_object = Sample(users=user1, users=user2)
sample_object.save()
```

I know that's wrong, but I'm sure you get what I want to do. How would you do it ?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You cannot create m2m relations from unsaved objects. If you have the `pk`s, try this:

```
sample_object = Sample()
sample_object.save()
sample_object.users.add(1,2)
```

**Update:** After reading the [saverio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field/6999006#6999006), I decided to investigate the issue a bit more in depth. Here are my findings.

This was my original suggestion. It works, but isn't optimal. (Note: I'm using `Bar`s and a `Foo` instead of `User`s and a `Sample`, but you get the idea).

```
bar1 = Bar.objects.get(pk=1)
bar2 = Bar.objects.get(pk=2)
foo = Foo()
foo.save()
foo.bars.add(bar1)
foo.bars.add(bar2)
```

It generates a whopping total of 7 queries:

```
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 1
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 2
INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("name") VALUES ()
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (1))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 1)
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (2))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 2)
```

I'm sure we can do better. You can pass multiple objects to the `add()` method:

```
bar1 = Bar.objects.get(pk=1)
bar2 = Bar.objects.get(pk=2)
foo = Foo()
foo.save()
foo.bars.add(bar1, bar2)
```

As we can see, passing multiple objects saves one `SELECT`:

```
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 1
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 2
INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("name") VALUES ()
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (1, 2))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 2)
```

I wasn't aware that you can also assign a list of objects:

```
bar1 = Bar.objects.get(pk=1)
bar2 = Bar.objects.get(pk=2)
foo = Foo()
foo.save()
foo.bars = [bar1, bar2]
```

Unfortunately, that creates one additional `SELECT`:

```
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 1
SELECT "app_bar"."id", "app_bar"."name" FROM "app_bar" WHERE "app_bar"."id" = 2
INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("name") VALUES ()
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."id", "app_foo_bars"."foo_id", "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE "app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (1, 2))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 2)
```

Let's try to assign a list of `pk`s, as saverio suggested:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.save()
foo.bars = [1,2]
```

As we don't fetch the two `Bar`s, we save two `SELECT` statements, resulting in a total of 5:

```
INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("name") VALUES ()
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."id", "app_foo_bars"."foo_id", "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE "app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (1, 2))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 2)
```

And the winner is:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.save()
foo.bars.add(1,2)
```

Passing `pk`s to `add()` gives us a total of 4 queries:

```
INSERT INTO "app_foo" ("name") VALUES ()
SELECT "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" FROM "app_foo_bars" WHERE ("app_foo_bars"."foo_id" = 1  AND "app_foo_bars"."bar_id" IN (1, 2))
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO "app_foo_bars" ("foo_id", "bar_id") VALUES (1, 2)
```

Comment: I'd like to add, you can pass a list with * like so: foo.bars.add(*list) 
and it will explode the list into arguments :D

Comment: This should be the Django Docs about ManyToMany! much clearer then https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/, and also with the performance penalties for the different method included. Maybe you can update it for Django 1.9? (the set method)

Comment: I want to save model with single id with more then one item and quantity.
Will it be possible??

class Cart(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name="item")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

Comment: Wow. I'm amazed. :D

Answer (score 134):

For future visitors, you can create an object and all of its m2m objects in **2 queries** using the new **[bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)** in django 1.4. Note that this is only usable if you don't require *any* pre or post-processing on the data with save() methods or signals. What you insert is exactly what will be in the DB

You can do this without specifying a "through" model on the field. For completeness, the example below creates a blank Users model to mimic what the original poster was asking.

```
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
    pass

class Sample(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Users)
```

Now, in a shell or other code, create 2 users, create a sample object, and bulk add the users to that sample object.

```
for _ in range(2):  # Create some Users
    Users().save()

users = Users.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2])

sample_object = Sample()
sample_object.save()

# Access the through model directly
ThroughModel = Sample.users.through
ThroughModel.objects.bulk_create([
    ThroughModel(users_id=users[0].pk, sample_id=sample_object.pk),
    ThroughModel(users_id=users[1].pk, sample_id=sample_object.pk)
])
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28437208/1075247) but I'm getting stuck. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me, but I had to set the attributes in bulk_create to the model instances, not the IDs.

Answer (score 20):

**Django 1.9**
A quick example:

```
sample_object = Sample()
sample_object.save()

list_of_users = DestinationRate.objects.all()
sample_object.users.set(list_of_users)
```

Answer (score 9):

RelatedObjectManagers are different "attributes" than fields in a Model. The simplest way to achieve what you are looking for is

```
sample_object = Sample.objects.create()
sample_object.users = [1, 2]
```

That's the same as assigning a User list, without the additional queries and the model building.

If the number of queries is what bothers you (instead of simplicity), then the optimal solution requires three queries:

```
sample_object = Sample.objects.create()
sample_id = sample_object.id
sample_object.users.through.objects.create(user_id=1, sample_id=sample_id)
sample_object.users.through.objects.create(user_id=2, sample_id=sample_id)
```

This will work because we already know that the 'users' list is empty, so we can create mindlessly.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the set of related objects in this way (new in Django 1.9):

```
new_list = [user1, user2, user3]
sample_object.related_set.set(new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone is looking to do David Marbles answer on a self referring ManyToMany field. The ids of the through model are called:
"to_'model_name_id" and
"from_'model_name'_id".

If that doesn't work you can check the django connection.