# django 1.4 Many-to-Many bulk add

Tags: django, many-to-many

I was wondering if there is the equivalent of a "add all" or "bulk create" for many to many relationships which reduce the number of queries (I will be doing this for a long list)?

The docs on this subject seem to suggest that this is not possible:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

```
**Associate the Article with a Publication:**
a1.publications.add(p1)

**Create another Article, and set it to appear in both Publications:**
a2 = Article(headline='NASA uses Python')
a2.save()
a2.publications.add(p1, p2)
a2.publications.add(p3)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course it's possible! You just have to create an explicit [intermediate table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and
then use this model's `bulk_create` method.

Comment: Actually, an explicit intermediate table isn't necessary, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10116452/5112

Comment: @Tim I've forgotten about it. Good catch!

Comment: This is an extremely good idea if someone wishes to use the Postgresql COPY command (like [this app](https://github.com/california-civic-data-coalition/django-postgres-copy) does) instead of the django ORM for faster results with huge volumes of data.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to add queryset to bulk add or remove method of many to many relation models :

```
qs = Article.objects.all()
publications = Publications.objects.get(id=1)

publications.article_set.add(*qs)
publications.save()
publications.article_set.remove(*qs)
publications.save()
```

Comment: You can also just use `publications.article_set.set(qs)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

An example that adds a group and assign its permissions

```
group = Group.objects.create(name='user_manager')
codenames = ['delete_user', 'add_user', 'view_user', 'change_user']
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(codename__in=codenames)
group.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`RelatedManager.set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) for this:

```
a2 = Article(headline='NASA uses Python')
a2.save()
a2.publications.set([p1, p2, p3])
```

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) also tells us that there's no need to call `.save()` at the end.

Comment: And yet, set is not the same as add. The equivalent of add-without-set is create().

Comment: @Melvyn, Yeah, since `set()` replaces all the existing relations.