# instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm going to get mad now - I could not create a new Team-Instance. Django always displays the error: `'Team' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Here's my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            # for later use
            pass
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I'd like to create a new Team...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import Team

user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=1)
new = Team()
new.name = 'aaa'
new.save()
new.members.add(user_obj)
```

Could someone see the mistake?

**edit**
i've read the docs and this (very great) answer [How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field) - still can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: This code looks correct. Maybe the error is located elsewhere? Is this your whole code or is it truncated? Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: there's a custom save method - but it only calls the `super(Team, self)...`- here's the stacktrace: http://dpaste.com/814410/

Comment: The only way I could see this happening is that somehow your save() method is not committing to the database. Please include the code for your custom save() method.

Comment: updated question with save() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, it is in your save() method. Try this fix:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if obj.id:
        # for later use
        pass
    return obj
```

Answer (score 1):

@init3's accepted answer didn't work for me because obj kept resolving to 'NoneType', in other words, call to super didn't return anything. Got it working as:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.pk:
        pass
```