# Why doesn't RelatedManager.add() accept an iterable as an argument?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This question is about [RelatedManager.add()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) which is used to add model object instances to a many-to-one or many-to-many relation. To illustrate my question, let's say I have the following two models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Now, for each `Author` I have a list of `Book` objects that I want to add to the relation. At the moment, I'm doing it like this:

```
book_objects = [
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone>, 
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets>,
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban>
]

jk_rowling = Author.objects.get(name='J. K. Rowling')

for book in book_objects:
    jk_rowling.books.add(book)
jk_rowling.save()
```

However, this is not very efficient as I have to deal with thousands of objects to be added to a relation of this kind and it takes ages. Rather, the Django documentation [recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/optimization/#insert-in-bulk) to call `add()` with more than one model object as an argument. That is, I would have to do it like the following:

```
jk_rowling.books.add(book1, book2, book3)
```

But I cannot do this because I don't know the number of objects added to the relation beforehand. I don't understand why I can't do the following:

```
jk_rowling.books.add(book_objects)
```

Why doesn't `add()` accept an iterable as an argument? And how can I add a large amount of objects to a relation like this more efficiently than calling `add()` for each object separately? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field

Comment: @init3 Ah, this is interesting. I wasn't aware of the fact that you can actually pass a list of primary keys to the relation like this: `jk_rowling.books = [1, 2, 3]`. This is not stated in Django's documentation. Great, this should save me some database queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just expand your array as varargs:

```
book_objects = [
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone>, 
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets>,
    <Book: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban>
]

jk_rowling = Author.objects.get(name='J. K. Rowling')

jk_rowling.books.add(*book_objects)   # <---------------

jk_rowling.save()
```

Comment: Oh my! Why haven't I thought about that? It totally makes sense. Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of trouble. :)