# Bulk update for many to many fields

Tags: django, many-to-many, bulk

I have two models as Follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=4)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(null=true, blank=true)


class Author(models.CustomUser):
    # some fields
```

Now, what I am looking to do is add an `Author` to multiple `Book` objects without iterating over the list of book objects.

Django's update method does not support `ManyToManyField` as per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). It says:

> You can only set non-relation fields and ForeignKey fields using this method. To update a non-relation field, provide the new value as a constant. To update ForeignKey fields, set the new value to be the new model instance you want to point to.

So currently I am doing the following which is highly inefficient as I'll be hitting the database for each book object.

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
books = Book.objects.filter(**kwargs) # say this returns 100 objects
# each loop here will hit the database making it really inefficient
# for long lists.
for book in books:
    book.authors.add(author)
    book.save()
```

I am pretty sure there is a way around this, but I am just not able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ check this.....Adding via the ‘other’ end of an m2m section ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field)

Answer (score 22):

The answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116452/202168

In short, (in Django >= 1.4) you can do a `bulk_create` on the through model, even if you haven't defined a custom through model.

Comment: thanks for the down-vote anonymous down-voter... what would be even more helpful is to add a comment explaining briefly what's wrong with my answer

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should provide an actual answer, not just link to one.

Comment: I did provide an answer

Answer (score 10):

Django - 2.27
Python 3.8

Let filter out the set of books

```
books = Book.objects.filter(...)
```

Create a author

```
author = Author.objects.create(...)
```

Add related_name for author field in Book model as author_book.

```
...
author = models.ManyToManyField(null=true, blank=true, related_name="author_book")
...
```

now add the author into set of books using reverse relation technique.

```
author.author_book.add(*books)
```

use * to unpack the query set

Note: we do not need to explicitly call save()

Comment: I think its important to note that running `.add()` actually saves the addition as well, which is the entire ppint of bulk_update(). Good answer, I think it is overlooked since not many people realize that it does indeed save

Comment: Yeh. It does saves as well

Comment: Where does it come from? Any link in the doc?

Comment: It can't work: the related name `author_book` is not an attribute of `author` but of `book`. It should be `author.book.add(*books)`. But it doesn't solve the `bulk_update` problem neither.