# Passing id's to many to many creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following association in my Rails app:

```
Order has_and_belongs_to_many Type
Type has_and_belongs_to_many Order
```

There is a join table called OrdersTypes.

I know I can do `Order.create(:types => [Type.first])`.

However, if I am designing an API and I want the User to be able to create an order with just a Type id, how would the parameters look?

Something like `Order.create(:type_ids => [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field)

Comment: Do you mean create an order with single Type id ?

Answer (score 0):

You would do

```
Order.create(:type_id => params['id'].map(&:to_i) )
```

where params['id'] are the ids taken as input from user

Comment: I get this: ``ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: type_id``

Comment: Do you have a type id in Order table as foreign key and is allowed as a strong parameter?