# how to save Many to Many relationship in django

Tags: python, django

[How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field)

From above question i come to know we can save Many to Many field later only.

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Foo(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(upload_to='')
   store = models.ManyToManyField(Store, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
new_track.file = request.FILES['file']
new_track.save()
```

And file uploading working fine then later i modify my code to add store then i am here...

Now i am sure db return id's here. Then i tried with my below code but that's given me error only

```
    x = new_track.id
    new = Foo.objects.filter(id=x)
    new.store.id = request.POST['store']
    new.save()
```

ok so the error here is `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'store'`

And also i tried with `add` that's now working either. 
So the question is how to save()

Comment: try to change your code into new.store = request.POST['store']

Comment: `.filter` returns a queryset. To get an object, you need a `.get()` or `.filter()[0]`

Comment: @karthikr I am damn sure getting the id value when save. Is my method correct way for saving many to many relation ? If i do my way i am getting `Foo' object has no attribute 'name'` well i tried yours too. And doniyor told different method return store object then save using add method. What is correct way ? please help

Comment: @cdvv7788 i changed my question please take look into it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the right way of saving objects with manytomany relations would be:

```
...
new_track.file = request.FILES['file']
new_track.save()

new_store = Store.objects.get(id=int(request.POST['store']))
new_track.store.add(new_store)
```

Comment: I tried yours and getting error like `nvalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on'`

Comment: @em___life Try this ``new_store = Store.objects.get(id=int(request.POST['store']))``

Comment: ok.. there is no error right now. I guess object is saving. Then i visited mysql workbench, table 'dsp_foo_store` there three field is there (id, foo_id, store_id). If foo_id is 9 then the corresponding store_id 3 but i select multiple means more than three checkbox but it return only one object. How come ?

Comment: @em___life (dont forget to upvote and check as answer if it solved your first problem). i dont understand what you mean by ``"i select multiple means more than three checkbox"``. can you describe this case a little more

Comment: I have doubt like `objects.get` return only one object but `request.POST['store']` return more than one value bcse each checkbox rendered store `ids`.....

Comment: and also i checked in workbench only one id saved in store_id field. This is suppose to be multiple values right ?.. Instead of saving multiple value why only one value save into store_id .

Comment: Your solution is right .. But i need this doubts .. I cant' able to upvote bcse i have only 5 reputation ..

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, here's my approach to saving ManyToMany Field to a given object.

**Short Answer**

```
class HostingRequestView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = VideoGameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.updated_by = request.user
            obj.save()

            selected_categories = form.cleaned_data.get('category') #returns list of all selected categories e.g. ['Sports','Adventure']
            #Now saving the ManyToManyField, can only work after saving the form
            for title in selected_categories:
                category_obj = Category.objects.get(title=title) #get object by title i.e I declared unique for title under Category model
                obj.category.add(category_obj) #now add each category object to the saved form object
            return redirect('confirmation', id=obj.pk)
```

**Full Answer**

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)

class VideoGame(models.Model):
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category) #ManyToMany Category field
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date added")
```

forms.py ModelForm

```
class VideoGameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('Detective', 'Detective'),
        ('Sports', 'Sports'),
        ('Action', 'Action'),
        ('Adventure', 'Adventure'),
    )

    category = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CATEGORIES, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = VideoGame
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'date_added']
```

views.py on POST

```
class HostingRequestView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = VideoGameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.updated_by = request.user
            obj.save()

            selected_categories = form.cleaned_data.get('category') #returns list of all selected categories e.g. ['Sports','Adventure']
            #Now saving the ManyToManyField, can only work after saving the form
            for title in selected_categories:
                category_obj = Category.objects.get(title=title) #get object by title i.e I declared unique for title under Category model
                obj.category.add(category_obj) #now add each category object to the saved form object
            return redirect('confirmation', id=obj.pk)
```

URL path for redirect

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('confirmation/<int:id>/', Confirmation.as_view(), name='confirmation'),
]
```

I hope this can be helpful. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
new.stores.all()
```

returns all stores linked to the object.

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: the error he is receiving is with the store, which should be queried as stores.filter or as any model objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

1. Change Foo to Tracks
2. Tracks.objects.filter(id=x) to Tracks.objects.get(id=x)

Let me know how it goes

Comment: i Changed my question please take look into it

Comment: @em___life Check my second recommendation. Filter returns a list of results (you can view querysets like that) and you want an object. Change filter by get or try filter()[0]

Answer (score 0):

why this confusion so much.. you are getting the id there then, call the store like

```
new_track.save()
new_track.store.add(request.POST['store'])
```

Comment: Thanks now the choice filed is saving but i have multiple choice entry then mysql give me this error `(1062, "Duplicate entry '4-5' for key 'tracks_id'")`

Comment: ``request.POST['store']`` is just a string, you cannot ``.add()`` as manytomany related object