# Django / Python - Using ManyToMany field In Object Creation

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there any way to create an object in a model using a ManyToManyField?

Here are the models:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    tour_ref = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

The task is to create a new Booking object. But how do I do this using specific customers from the Customer table? (I would be identifying them by email). (Obviously more than one customer would be likely).

Many thanks!

Comment: This explains some possibilities `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `add` to add list of customers to new booking:

```
booking = Booking.object.create(tour_ref="ref")
customers = list(Customer.objects.filter(email="email@mail.com"))
booking.customers.add(customers)
```

or you can add booking to specific customer using reverse lookup `booking_set` and `create`:

```
booking = Booking.object.create(tour_ref="ref")
customer.booking_set.create(tour_ref="ref")
```