# How can update many_to_many relational fields with bulk_update() method in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can I update `many_to_many` fields with the `bulk_update` method in `Django`?

**Code:**

```py
get_user_model().objects.using('default').bulk_update(
    User.objects.using('default').all(), ('password','groups')
)
```

**Error:**

> {ValueError}bulk_update() can only be used with concrete fields.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116452/4751726