# When an object is created with an admin form, how can to create related objects?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I create a `PotatoBatch` item via my admin form, I want many `Potato` objects to be created.

`Potato` has a `ForeignKey` to `PotatoBatch`.

I made a `PotatoBatchCreateForm` that has an extra field, "number_of_potatoes". When I save this form, I want it to generate the correct number of potatoes for this batch.

I wanted to override my `PotatoBatchCreateForm`'s save method like this :

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        potato_batch = super().save() # save the potato_batch object in order to have an object id
        number_of_potatoes = self.cleaned_data['number_of_potatoes']
        for i in range(number_of_potatoes):
            potato_batch.potato_set.create()
        return potato_batch
```

But this fails with a `'PotatoBatchCreateForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'` error.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create the m2m relationships until after the instance is saved. From your brief example I think this would work.

```
for i in range(number_of_potatoes):
    myPotato = Potato.objects.create()
    myPotato.potato_batch = potato_batch
    myPotato.save()
return potato_batch
```

More In-depth explanation:
[How to create an object for a Django model with a many to many field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996176/how-to-create-an-object-for-a-django-model-with-a-many-to-many-field)

Comment: Hi @Erik. It's not an m2m relationship though, it's a foreignkey/one-to-many, so why is it affected ?

Comment: @MonsieurPoivron That is a good point, I don't know. Its difficult to tell with the limited context, but it could be a factor of using objects.create(). Most examples I see and use have an instance being created with the constructor i.e. myPotato = Potato(), saving it, and then relationships are created through signals.

I usually use bulk_create() in this situation. Just create Potato() instances inside of your loop, include the potato_batch reference as you have been and append each instance to a list. Then when your loop is finished just do Potato.objects.bulk_create(list_of_potatoes)