# exclude many-to-many with specific value in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model:

```py
class Rent(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bikes = models.ManyToManyField(Bike)
```

when I create a new rent in the admin site, I would like to exclude the bikes that have the value of 1 for their status integer field from showing in the list to choose from. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that from the Admin site. <strike>probably you cannot.</strike> But you can do it from views. just select the model objects you need with query and pass it into the field. I am attaching a ell explained similar scenario. condition your query and add those objects.

[Adding many to many fields based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996358/8401179)

Comment: Thanks!, Yes I'm aware of this option, however I need it in the admin site if possible, I've seen something like `limit_choice_to` work with `foregin_key` but I don't really know how to achieve that with the many to many.

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) the admin form.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform) is a discussion of how to filter your form choices.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I figured it out, the problem was that the `limit_choices_to` doesn't work when I change the filter to inline and I found others with the same problem, so I just changed it to `filter_horizontal` and now it works as it should